# Problem with publishing via instagram api

Tags: facebook, instagram

, if you're here, that's maybe because you're trying to help me, so ... thank you :)

i'm trying to use the explorer graph api tool given by facebook :

when i try to publish via this tool (i'd like to post later with curl)
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=%20103371141816250&version=v10.0

when i do a post request with my POST /{instagram-id}, i get {success : true} as response (that means that my instagram id is existing)
but when i try to post with this :

POST graph.facebook.com/{instagram-id}/media?{image-url},

or this

POST graph.facebook.com/{instagram-id}/media?image_url={image-url}&access_token={access_token}

i get the following response :

{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID '{instagram-id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "A9okqmqtgx85S8kSf1wxITo"
}
}

can anyone help me about this? my expected behavior for this query is to publish the content i gave as image_url :)

my facebook app is sstill in "developpment mode", do you think this might be the reason it doesnt work?

thanks guys!

Comment: Don’t see any point in making a request `POST /{instagram-id}`, what is that supposed to achieve, posting directly to the account ID? The error message you are getting, usually indicates that permissions are lacking on the access token used.

Comment: thanks @CBroe
i specified all the permissions there was (46 of them), the POST /{instagram-id} was just to check that my instagram user was valid

Comment: If you want to check the existence of data, then use a GET request, not POST.

Comment: What _kind_ of IG account is this?

Comment: this is a professionnal instagram account (contractor / entrepreneur) 
thanks, i'll remember this :)

Comment: Can’t tell if that is supposed to mean _business_ account, or _creator_ account. According to the documentation, publishing seems only possible for business accounts.

Comment: Have you applied for the Instagram permissions? You'll need several including: instagram_basic
instagram_content_publish

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing

Comment: Thanks  @Geoffrey, i'm first using the explorer for testings :) 
i tried to implement the login with facebook, but this doesn't work since i'm working on local (=> no HTTPS, which is required for facebook logni to work if i recall correctly)